# How to ensure empty XML tag still contains the parent key?

Tags: xml, xsd, sqlxml

I have a relationship between a parent Foo and its child Bar.  When Bar contains anything within it, then it is mapped into a table containing the child-key column "FooID".

For instance, if the XML contains:

```
<Bar>
    <Anything/>
</Bar>
```

then the FooID column will be populated.

```
|FooID|OtherColumns |...|
|--| --- | --- |
|FooID_1 |  | |
```

However, my problem is that when Bar is empty or a self closing tag, then FooID is not populated.  Is there a way to make a change from within the XML so that the child-key is set on the child even if the child is empty?

Current problematic functionality:

```
<Bar></Bar>
    OR
<Bar/>
```

results in:

```
|FooID|OtherColumns |...|
|--| --- | --- |
| |  | |
```

My .XSD:

```
<sql:relationship name="Foo_Bar" parent="Foo" parent-key="id" child="Bar" child-key="FooID"/>
<xsd:element name="Foo" sql:relation="Foo" sql:relationship="SomeRel_Foo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            ...
            <xsd:element name="Bar" sql:relation="Bar" sql:relationship="Foo_Bar">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="SomeElement1" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="SomeElement2" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:attribute name="FooID" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            ...
```

UPDATE:

I also tried the following:

```
<xsd:attribute name="FooID" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>  
     AND  
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="OrgForm" type="xsd:string" />
```

Comment: I don’t know SQL/XML so I am just guessing that you have to define the children as optional e.g. with minOccurs="0" on the inner sequence tag.

Comment: @FLUXparticle I tried adding `minOccurs="0"` to the sequence, its elements, and even the top-level element.  None of this worked.  I am suspecting the xsd:attribute may have something to do with this?

In other words, I'm still getting the Bar element loaded into the DB, which is perhaps what the minOccurs is for.  However, the attribute FooID is not getting set.